# Re-Use the resources after finish()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have several Activities in my application named, *MainActivity*, *ChangeActivity* and some others.

MainActivity displays some images from internet and refresh the page after a specific time. *ChangeActivity* will alter some data in *MainActivity*, so the images in Main page will be changed accordingly and on Submit will return back to *MainActivity*.

The application works fine, when it starts. But when I navigate from MainActivity  to ChangeActivity, the previous MainActivity remains as it is and again a new Activity starts. As the previous MainActivity is still alive, it will try to auto refresh, eventually after repeating the same procedure for several times, it takes a huge time to load images in Main page.

I am looking for a solution, so I can destroy the previous MainActivities and have only have one, so the images from internet can download faster. Also other activities use the data from MainActivity. So destroying this completely might affect others.

Please do let me know, how I can utilize the resources effectively without affecting the other activities.

Comment: Instance of Activity is not guaranteed to stay alive even if application is alive. To put it in a simple way, consider storing resources at application level - as static fields/singletons or as member of `Application` instance. Or, consider using other libraries which do that for you, such as Picasso.

Answer (score -1):

You can add finish() right after you start another activity. For example if you are starting activity ChangeActivity from MainActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChangeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```